# Get the space of Secondary hard disk - c++

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, hard-drive

With the below link I am able to get the hard disk space.

[Get Hard Disk Space](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?424302-disk-space)

But if I connect a secondary hard disk it's not showing the details of it.

How can I loop the number of hard disks and retrieve their spaces?

I would like to get that in a loop sector. Get hard disk count and loop for drives in harddisk1 and then loop for drives in harddisk2 like that.

Comment: You should probably tag this as windows specific, unless you are looking for a cross platform approach?

Comment: possible duplicate of [enumerating all drives and extracting information about each one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14197247/getlogicaldrives-plus-additional-information-c)

Answer (score 1):

Use Windows API's [`GetLogicalDriveStrings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364975%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.

```
std::vector< std::basic_string<TCHAR> > drives;

TCHAR szBuffer[1024];
::GetLogicalDriveStrings(1024, szBuffer);
TCHAR *pCurrentDrive = szBuffer;
while (*pCurrentDrive)
{
   drives.push_back( pCurrentDrive );
   pCurrentDrive = &pCurrentDrive[_tcslen(pCurrentDrive) + 1];
}
```

Then call `GetDiskFreeSpaceEx` for every element in the `drives` vector.

You could also use the `GetLogicalDrives` function instead, which returns the drives as a bit mask. However, I think `GetLogicalDriveStrings` is simpler in this case, because it returns the drives as strings which you can pass to `GetDiskFreeSpaceEx` directly.

Comment: Thanks. But I would like to get that in a loop sector. Get harddisk count and loop for drives in harddisk1 and then loop for drives in harddisk1 like that

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
for (char drive = 'a'; drive <= 'z'; drive++)
{
    // Get for amount for `drive`
}
```

---

And for those who are wondering... Yes this is very naive and probably time-consuming.

Comment: You can use GetLogicalDrives to get a bitmask of the available drives.

Comment: This can cause your old floppy drive to start grinding.